# Find function(map) for given input and output strings

Tags: machine-learning

I have a large set of string inputs/outputs like

651804305 -> 65204305180

651804320 -> 65204320180

821003145 -> 82003145100

...

I'd like to find(guess) the function that maps these inputs to outputs.
Is this a known problem?! What are the famous algorithms used here?!

Comment: What is the nature of the assumed function between I/O?

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos idk for sure but my guess is string modifications, e.g. shifting some characters, adding some characters ...

Comment: Are the string lengths set or at least upper-bound? Are multiple inputs mapped to the same output? How many potential unique outputs are you expecting?

Comment: in 95% of cases input is 9 characters and output 11 characters, there are exceptions, but I would say we don't need to worry about those. And it's supposed to be 1 to 1 mapping